# Check for files ending in .zip.part in specified directory in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to write a Python script in Python3 that uses Selenium and saves files to a directory. Upon searching Google, I found that Selenium apparently doesn't have a function to wait for a download to complete, and as I'm using Firefox as the web driver, I instead want to check the download directory (defined as a string) in the script every second until there are no files ending in ".zip.part", which would indicate the download has completed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See `glob.glob()`.

Answer (score 0):

To check your Downloads folder and wait until download is complete, you can use the code below.

NOTES:

- replace */Users/Test/Downloads/* by path on your machine
- as you're checking the condition of absent .zip.part files instead of number of successfully downloaded zip files (which I would suggest you), you should carefully call the waiting for each files. Otherwise code may decide that download is complete in the point of time when some file was already downloaded and next one is yet to be downloaded.
- [waiting](https://pypi.org/project/waiting/) lib is used for waiting

  ```
   import glob
   import os

   from waiting import wait, TimeoutExpired


   def no_partial_download_files(download_path):
       return len(glob.glob(os.path.join(download_path, '*.zip.part'))) == 0


   timeout_seconds = 20
   try:
       wait(lambda: no_partial_download_files('/Users/Test/Downloads/'), timeout_seconds=timeout_seconds)
   except TimeoutExpired:
       print('Download did not complete within timeout', timeout_seconds)
   else:
       print('Download has completed')
  ```